# PostGIS: ST_Contains with a lat/long pair and GeoJSON text

Tags: postgresql, geospatial, postgis

Heyo,

I have a table that contains latitude/longitude columns, and another that contains GeoJSON in the form of a string.

I'd like to join the tables on the points from one table being within the polygons in the other. I've got something like this:

```
select s.id, s.name, s.city, s.province, cz."geoJson" from "TheZones" cz
   inner join "OtherTable" s 
   on st_contains(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(cz."geoJson"), st_point(s.latitude, s.longitude));
```

This is spitting out the error: `ERROR: contains: Operation on mixed SRID geometries (Polygon, 4326) != (Point, 0)`

No matter how I cast or transform these I can't seem to get it to work. Thoughts?

Comment: if you wrap the st_point into st_transform(st_point(...), 4326) it still shows this error?

Answer (score 4):

As the error says, your 2nd point has no projection set. You can set the SRID by using `ST_SetSRID` so your where clause becomes:

```
on st_contains(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(cz."geoJson"),
   st_setsrid(st_point( s.longitude, s.latitude),4326))
```

**Note:** you also need to use longitude, latitude when using 4326 with PostGIS.

Comment: you can also pass srid directly to st_point: `st_point(s.longitude, s.latitude, 4326)`